# Adding Google Analytics to my podfile breaks the build (library not found)

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, cocoapods

I have Google Analytics in my project which works fine. Once I move it to my pod file everything breaks.

In my pod:

```
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'  
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
```

The pod update log:

```
Installing Google (1.0.7)
Using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.3.1)
Installing GoogleAnalytics (3.12.0)
Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.0.0)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.0.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (1.0.1)
```

I get this error:

> ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've noticed it breaks and spams the "library search paths" in the build settings.

[image: Broken library search paths]

I have Google ads SDK in my pod file and that has been working fine.

Anyone know what is wrong here? If it's a bug then whose fault it would be?

**Edit:**
Updated to Cocoapods to 0.38.2, no change.

In my pod xcconfig file, the var "LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS" gets edited when I include Google Analytics and it removes "$(inherited)":

Example:

> LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(PODS_ROOT)/Google/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/Google/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
>   "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"

It looks to be a bug.

**Edit 2:**
I have created a bug report here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3908

Comment: You probably have conflicts between old integration and CocoaPods. See suggestion to create a new Xcode project, if it is at all an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a bug report here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3908

They agreed it was a bug so the best solution is to wait until it is fixed.

I believe I could hack to add "$(inherited)" to get it working but personally I'll pass on this.

Edit: Bug was fixed and released. No more problems.

Answer (score 2):

Trying your setup as described on a brand new Xcode project, and using the **Podfile** as below, there is no such error.

**First suggestion:**
Make a new project, `pod init`, add your Pod requirements, `pod install`, build, link and run.

```
target 'GooglePod' do
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'  
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
end

target 'GooglePodTests' do

end
```

**Second suggestion:**

Verify the configurations.

[image]

Comment: This is a very large project. When I have time I might try starting again.

Comment: Then I further suggest to do a `sudo gem install cocoapods` which will bring you to the latest tools, if any.

Comment: I believe I was on the current version. I could try out the beta later and see if anything is fixed there.

Comment: Thanks for all your help but it looks like this is a bug. I have updated the original post.

Comment: Does this post give you any hint? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641498/bridge-google-drive-api-to-swift/31641508#31641508

Comment: No that is a different problem. I can solve this by adding the missing "$(inherited)" myself but this is hacky so I'll wait until they fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Select the product -> Go to edit scheme -> select build -> and finally add pods.