# Bridge Google Drive API to Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

From a [previously removed post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638004/bridge-google-drive-api-to-swift):

> I am struggling to get the Google Drive API to work with Swift, and hoping someone has a suggestion. Here is where I am at so far: I have the Google Drive API installed and working in an Objective-C ...

I am trying to reproduce [this example from Google](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart) in Swift, but `import GTLDrive` returns an error in Xcode:

> No such module 'GTLDrive.

I am unable to use `GTLServiceDrive` from the Swift classes.
Which combination of CocoaPod + *bridging header* should I use?

Comment: This is a non-trivial question posted 5 hours ago from another users that was removed before it was answered. Solution below.

Answer (score 6):

You need 3 things:

**(1) Well formed Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'GoogleDrive' do
pod 'Google-API-Client/Drive', '~> 1.0'
end
```

**(2) Expose Google API through the `bridging headers`**

```
#import "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"
#import "GTLDrive.h"
```

**(3) No reference GTLDrive required in the Swift client class**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // ...

    let service:GTLServiceDrive = GTLServiceDrive()
    service.authorizer = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.authForGoogleFromKeychainForName("Drive API",
        clientID: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
        clientSecret: "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE")

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to solve the issue described here: https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/103 (without reverting to manual integration - that is, still using "Pods")

Comment: Please post a new question alongside the `Podfile` you are using. You can reference your question in a comment.

Comment: There is already a question regarding this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33581805/2586599

Comment: Ok, found the answer. Your answer above includes use of 3rd party unofficial pod. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36246255/2586599

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into that now in XCode 7.3, and fixed it with the following in the bridging header:

```
#import <GoogleAPIClient/GTLDrive.h>
```

Also, if you need the authentication portion:

```
#import <GTMOAuth2/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

I threw away Google API Objective C library from Swift altogether and created an interim solution: https://github.com/metaprgmr/GoogleApiProxyForSwift. Incidentally, I used Google Drive as a guinnea pig, where you can find experiments at close to the end of its YouTube presentation. Check it out.

Comment: Nice. Out of pure curiosity, didn't the solution I outlined work for you?