# cocoapods - use_frameworks! cause problems for some pods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, object, cocoapods

I'm using cocoapods in my swift project, some of my pods are Objective-C and some are Swift.
I added `use_frameworks!` to enable some pods like `RealmSwift`

now im trying to add the `SlackTextViewController` pod, but without success.

I added `pod 'SlackTextViewController'` to the `Podfile`

and `#import "SLKTextViewController.h"` to the `Bridge-Header.h` file

but I'm getting compile time error `"SLKTextViewController.h" file not found`

I think the problem is with the `use_frameworks!` flag

so i guess some pods require this flag and some pods can't compile with it,
any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, some libraries like GoogleAnalytics and others don't admit `use_frameworks` yet!!!

Comment: @VictorSigler so any workaround??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641498/bridge-google-drive-api-to-swift/31641508#31641508