# Import Objective-C Framework (CocoaPod) into Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2, cocoapods, libjingle

I'm trying to import the `libjingle_peerconnection` framework into my Xcode project, but for some reason I can't import the Objective-C header with `import RTCICEServer` in Swift source files. I have attempted to use header files, etc. What am I doing wrong?

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'VideoRTCTest' do
    pod "libjingle_peerconnection"
end

target 'VideoRTCTestTests' do

end

target 'VideoRTCTestUITests' do

end
```

[image]

Comment: Yup I am. libjingle_peerconnection is Objective-C if that helps.

Comment: I have not; I had to put it down, work is crazy busy right now. I'll come back to it when I can. Likely going to fall back to Objective-C.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Bridge

**1. Create a xxx-Bridging-Header**

Add a bridging header to your project using the method of your choice, the easiest one being creating a single `.m` file and answering **Create Bridging Header** to this dialog:

[image: Create Bridging Header]

**2. Reference your Pod in the bridging header**

Include your files as so:

```m
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that
// you would like to expose to Swift.

#import "RTCICEServer.h"
```

**3. Objective-C exposed to Swift**

Once in the bridging header, you need not import the Obj-C classes in Swift. Use these directly:

```swift
let uri = URL(fileURLWithPath: "")
let rtc:RTCICEServer = RTCICEServer(uri: uri, username: "", password: "")
print(rtc)
```

---

Another example is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31641508/218152).

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-34553684) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-34553684).

Comment: but the correct way is to import the module name (import xxxx) of the pod inside the swift file without having to create a bridging header as long as the pod file has the use_frameworks enabled, I believe there is something wrong with libjingle_peerconnection pod