# Obj C project swift file cannot see cocoa pods

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have an Objective C project that I added a swift file to - the swift file will contain convenience functions to the rest of my objc project. Adding the swift file triggered adding a bridging header - which I did. All of this works. I also have cocoapods configured and working from objc.

I can call a swift method from objc but my **swift file cannot see any of my swift cocoapod modules**. I get error 'no such module'. I've searched here extensively and have cleaned my project, cleaned the build folder checked my search paths- all appears ok. I am using use_frameworks! In my pod file.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your pod header to your bridging header as described here: [Import Objective-C Framework (CocoaPod) into Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553684/import-objective-c-framework-cocoapod-into-swift)

Comment: I may not have been clear but the Cocoapod framework is a swift framework, not Objective-C. When I do import SwiftChart in my swift file I get 'no such module'

Comment: Are you opening the workspace instead of the project? Strange that you can see a Swift module from Obj-C at all - it doesn't work going that direction, only C/Obj-C to Swift.